# why can't I send http requests outside of a web app?

Tags: mongodb, jestjs, localhost

when I try to make requests to a server running on localhost:8080, it sometimes gives a 404 or 405 error depending on the type of request. most recently this has happened when I try unit testing via JEST.

I know for a fact there's nothing wrong with the actual code because it works perfectly fine when other people run it on their PCs.

the exact same fetch requests that fail in unit tests work perfectly fine within a web application.

I first noticed this problem on Postman. The problem seems to occur when I try making requests just before or after the server has started listening, and then I have to wait for a bit before requests work again. Of course it makes sense that it wouldn't work when my server isn't listening yet, but the problem persists for a while after it does. This problem usually doesn't occur on postman anymore now that I make sure to wait for the server to start listening.

here's the response with a GET or POST request:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<h2>Access Error: 404 -- Not Found</h2>
<pre>Cannot open document for: /myroute/mypath</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

with a PUT request:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>Method Not Allowed</title></head>
<body>
<h2>Access Error: 405 -- Method Not Allowed</h2>
<pre>The &quot;PUT&quot; method is not supported by file handler</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

simple versions of the code I'm working with (again, I know for a fact this code works on a PC other than mine)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('../src/model/logboekTemplate.js');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const SERVERIP = "http://localhost:8080/logboeken/"

const dbName = 'rekenlogboek';

const Logboek = mongoose.model('Logboek');

describe('Logboeken route Tests', () => {


    beforeAll(async () => {

        mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost:27017/${dbName}`, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, retryWrites: false }).then().catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });

        await Logboek.deleteMany({});
    });

    beforeEach(async () => {

        await Logboek.create([
            {
                naam: "testlogboek",
            },
        ]);

    });

    afterEach(async () => {
        await Logboek.deleteMany({});
    });

    //laat de gehele lijst logboeken zien
    test('get /logboeklijst', async () => {
        let response = await fetch(SERVERIP + "/logboeklijst", {
            method: 'get', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
            mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
        });
        expect(response.status).toEqual(201);
        let body = await response.json()
        expect(body[0].naam).toEqual("testlogboek");
    })


})
```

This server works perfectly fine normally, it's just the unit tests that fail and even then only when I do it on my laptop.

```
const express = require('express')
const http = require('http')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);


app.use(bodyParser.text());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());


const { logboekRouter } = require('./routes/logboeken');
app.use('/logboeken', logboekRouter);



//-------------------------------------//
//Mongoose
//-------------------------------------//


let dbName;


        dbName = "rekenlogboek";
        mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost:27017/${dbName}`, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, retryWrites: false }).then().catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });

        server.listen(8080,
            function () {
                console.log("The Server is listening on port 8080.")
            });
```

and the command line

```
> project-tests@1.0.0 test C:\Users\Wouter\Documents\GitHub\{my project}
> jest --runInBand --verbose

(node:23248) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.
  console.warn
    Mongoose: looks like you're trying to test a Mongoose app with Jest's default jsdom test environment. Please make sure you read Mongoose's docs on configuring Jest to test Node.js apps: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/jest.html

      at Object.<anonymous> (deployment/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/printJestWarning.js:4:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (deployment/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:46:1)

 FAIL  deployment/routes/logboeken.test.js
  Logboeken route Tests
    × get /logboeklijst (42 ms)
  ● Logboeken route Tests › get /logboeklijst

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: 201
    Received: 404

      212 |             mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
      213 |         });
    > 214 |         expect(response.status).toEqual(201);
          |                                 ^
      215 |         let body = await response.json()
      216 |         expect(body[0].naam).toEqual("testlogboek");
      217 |     })

      at Object.<anonymous> (deployment/routes/logboeken.test.js:214:33)
          at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: You're making requests to *what* server exactly now…? You haven't really given us anything to work with. You have *a* server and that server sometimes returns 4xx errors… Well, okay… not much we can say about that.

Comment: Your unit tests shouldn't make *any* network requests.